# How to realize declared types and constants in Isabelle/HOL?

Tags: isabelle

I know that the `typedecl` and `consts` commands can be used in Isabelle (as of 2021) to declare a new type/constant without defining it. For example:

```
typedecl state

consts M :: "(state × state)set"

typedecl "atom"

consts L :: "state ⇒ atom set"
```

My questions are:

*Can one define the type/constants to be some actual type or constants after the declaration?*

*If so, can multiple definitions be defined in different theories to implement those declarations? (, so that the declaration serves as an interface)*

I have seen some old documents that use `defs` (plus `consts`) command to define things, but it no longer seems to be defined in Isabelle 2021.

Comment: Don't do that. Use locales instead. This is the proper mechanism and you cannot accidentally add inconsistencies.

Comment: @MathiasFleury Not sure if I completely agree. For (term) constants, the command `overloading` provides a standard mechanism to do what tinlyx is trying to achieve (the consistency issue was largely settled in the last few years, to the best of my knowledge). See subsection 5.9 in the [reference manual](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/isar-ref.pdf) for further information.

Comment: I was thinking of duplicate overloading (different definitions for the same type -- definition inconsistencies) more than of proof inconsistencies.

Comment: @MathiasFleury Right. I thought that you may have been referring to Isabelle/HOL’s logic inconsistency issue that was caused precisely by the presence of a mechanism for overloading. I have to admit, however, I am not certain if I understand what is meant by the “definition inconsistencies” and how could one produce such an inconsistency in Isabelle/HOL (an example would help here), but, I guess, we were thinking about different issues.

Comment: Clashing definitions (like having two orders on `'a option`, one with None at max and one with None as min). You might want to have two different definitions for the same type in two different theories (that you import together). Locales allow you to do that (with names abbreviation). And they are easier to manipulate (inherit, compose, ...).

Comment: @MathiasFleury Ah, thank you for clarifying this. However, now I disagree with the way your comment was phrased :-). Technically, if two theories would result in a clash of specifications, the system should not allow for them to be imported into a single theory. So, you cannot “accidentally add inconsistencies” (depending on how this statement is interpreted by less experienced readership). Also, in general, there exist useful applications for `overloading`, although I agree that one should ensure that there are no feasible alternative solutions before using this technology.